# Spring MVC Set parent object to a list with dynamic form

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So I have a dynamic form that I created with Thymeleaf and Spring MVC, and the parent object I have is called `StudySet` which has a list of `Rows`, and the rows are they're own object called `Row`.

Right now I have an `arrayList` of `rows` on the `StudySet` which I can see when I run my application in debug mode.  Which you can see in the picture below.

[image]

All I'm trying to do at this point is to set the studySet on to all of the rows, before I save the studySet and rows in my controller, so that in another part of my application, I can pull up the rows assigned to a specific studySet.

Here's my code in my POST method in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="createStudySet", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String createSetPost (@ModelAttribute StudySet studySet, ModelMap model, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {

studySet.setUser(user);
user.getStudySet().add(studySet);

List<Row> rows = studySet.getRows();
((List<Row>) ((Row) rows).getStudySet()).addAll((Collection<? extends Row>) studySet);


studySetRepo.save(studySet);   

return "redirect:/answers";
}
```

This code doesn't work, but I think it gives an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish with saving the `rows` to the `studySet`.

If anyone can see a way to fix my issue and help me out, that would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: excuse me, what do you mean by "set the studySet on to all of the rows" ?

Comment: In the same way I set the `studySet` to the `User` in the code above. In the `Row` domain object I have a variable called `StudySet studySet`, and I'm trying to set the `studySet` of the all the rows in the `arrayList`.  So that I can know what StudySet the Row is a part of.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is in this line:

```
((List<Row>) ((Row) rows).getStudySet()).addAll((Collection<? extends Row>) studySet);
```

As far as I understand your question you should do something like (or similar):

```
for (Row row : rows) {
    row.setStudySet(row.getStudySet().addAll(studySet))
}
```